# how to set rows color in dataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

If the status = "Incomplete" then rows color should be red. How can i do this?
Status field is in column 8.[DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFIDy.jpg)

```
String query = "select * from bug order by id desc;";
String Status = null;                     
DataTable dt = connection.retrieve(query);
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewDashboard.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Status = dataGridViewDashboard.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    if (Status == "Incomplete")
    {
        dataGridViewDashboard.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridViewDashboard.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: That question has been asked too many times.You can use **CellFormatting event** [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must subscribe to PrePaint event of DataGridView and you can set colors of row there ease.

```
  private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e){
if (your control here) 
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must control if is new row.

```
    String query = "select * from bug order by id desc;";
    String Status = null;                     
    DataTable dt = connection.retrieve(query);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewDashboard.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       if (dataGridViewDashboard.Rows[i].IsNewRow)
                continue;
        Status = dataGridViewDashboard.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        if (Status == "Incomplete")
        {
            dataGridViewDashboard.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridViewDashboard.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```